# disable autocorrectionType is not working with UITextfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have created `RegisterViewController` with email, password and confirm password fields.

In email field, it always show suggest email on QuickType's keyboard bar but other fields not show anything.

How it know which field is email or not ? I swear I didn't set anything to textfield.
I already set `autocorrectionType = .no` on my base class text field but it still show suggest on bar.

Can anyone help me about this ?

[image: keyboard screenshot showing suggestion bar]

Comment: this is not autocorrection. this is suggestion

Comment: Do u know how to remove it ? @FahimParkar

Answer (score 9):

Here's what you can try -

```
textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
textField.autocorrectionType = .no
textField.spellCheckingType = .no
```

Comment: Including both `autocorrectionType` and `spellCheckingType` worked for me.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: This worked for me, even with a delegate attached to the textField

Answer (score 0):

try `textField.textContentType = .none`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```swift
textField.disableAutocorrection(true)
textField.disableAutocorrection(false)
```

Or this:

```swift
textField.autocorrectionType = .yes
textField.autocorrectionType = .no
```

To hide the bar (predictive bar), use this code:

```swift
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    var item = textFeild.inputAssistantItem
    item.leadingBarButtonGroups = [];
    item.trailingBarButtonGroups = [];
}
```

This also may help in your case:

```swift
self.passwordField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.emailField.textContentType = .username
    self.emailField.keyboardType = .default
}
    
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    self.passwordField.textContentType = .password
    self.passwordField.keyboardType = .default
}
```

Comment: I got error has no member 'disableAutocorrection' ( I write it one swift 5 )

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know, This is cause issue or not, I put textfield on XIB file first and use it in storyboard.

Answer (score -1):

this is not autocorrection. this is suggestion

Use below code to disable suggestion

```swift
if #available(iOS 12, *) {
    // iOS 12 & 13: Not the best solution, but it works.
    passwordTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
} else {
    // iOS 11: Disables the autofill accessory view.
    // For more information see the explanation below.
    emailTextField.textContentType = .init(rawValue: "")
    passwordTextField.textContentType = .init(rawValue: "")
}
```

Comment: Still showing the suggestion bar for text fields with a `textContentType` set to `.oneTimeCode` for me (in iOS 15)

Comment: I suppose it makes sense though because at some point iOS introduced the automatic suggestion of SMS codes in that spot.