# Unable to disable autofill on keyboard on iOS 15 swift. Xcode 13

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, macos

I need to disable keyboard autofill. I used the following code:

```
firstName.autocorrectionType = .no
lastName.autocorrectionType = .no
        
firstName.textContentType = .none
lastName.textContentType = .none
```

On iOS 14 and older autofill is not shown.
[iOS 13.7 image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Luvd8.png).

On iOS 15 autofill is shown
[iOS 15 image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9uVM.png).

Has a new behavior been added for autofill on iOS 15 and how to disable it?

Comment: There are some suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68287217/disable-autocorrectiontype-is-not-working-with-uitextfield

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution this may helps you  disable textfield spellCheckingType also with autocorrectionType

```
firstName.autocorrectionType = .no
firstName.spellCheckingType = .no

lastName.autocorrectionType = .no
lastName.spellCheckingType = .no
```